# Which PIC MCU for an Audio player?

Tags: usb, audio, pic

#### DESCRIPTION:

It will play **.wav** and **.mp3** files from a Micro SD Card. The memory card can be written through USB (its an in-board unit). It will have a LCD screen to show the contents and functions like next, pause, previous, volume control and so on. Obviously, these functions can be remotely operated too.

I am familiar with PIC MCUs but being a beginner I have difficulties in deciding which MCU is enough for the job.

***Should I go for a PIC32 or dsPIC?*** I'd appreciate all suggestions regarding this project.

Comment: Some of the new series of the pic32 have a 0.5ma per mhz power use, which is about 1/3 of the dsPIC.

Answer (score 4):

The dsPIC seems to be not powerful enought to play an mp3, although you can use a dedicated chip to decode and the dsPIC to play the music and read the file on the SD card. A tutorial on a similar project can be seen at http://www.uchobby.com/index.php/2008/07/21/dspic-wav-player/

Microchip themselves have an application note on how to port Helix MP3 decoder to PIC32, (AN1367: http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1824&appnote=en551513) so that may be the natural choice.

Comment: Definitely, use a separate MP3 decoder.  You will have enough to do with dealing with the SD-card and file-system and USB.

Comment: Another reason to use a separate decoder is that if you choose to use the Helix MP3 decoder, you still have to pay royalties  (min $15,000 US/year!) to use the format - See http://www.mp3licensing.com/royalty/hardware.html.  For this reason, an external chip (such as those made by VLSI), with that fee paid by the IC manufacturer and distributed across all of their ICs is a nice option that keeps you out of legal trouble.

Comment: this one seems pretty ubiquitous http://www.vlsi.fi/en/products/vs1003.html (from VLSI as reemrevnivek said)

Comment: @reemrevnivek The link you posted is not accessible

Comment: @Vicky Rao, works for me.

Comment: Sparkfun sell a number of MP3 decoder ICs, and have breakout and demo boards for most of them. http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/advanced_search_result.php?keywords=mp3&search_section=products&x=0&y=0